# cocoapod - Circle Menu - Swift - How to interact with it

Tags: swift, animation, delegates, cocoapods, xcode8

I found this awesome looking cocoapod

- https://cocoapods.org/?q=lang%3Aswift%20on%3Aios%20circle%20menu

or

- https://github.com/Ramotion/circle-menu

but for the life of me i can't figure out how to interact with it. i think I'm getting confused with the delegate.  many get any of the functions to return an index or anything.

```
func circleMenu(_ circleMenu: CircleMenu, buttonWillSelected button: UIButton, atIndex: Int) {
    print("button will selected: \(atIndex)")
  }
```

doesn't actually return anything.

thanks for the help.

Comment: you can try the demo project which is available there in github

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to set the delegate to your button in story board, or programatically "button.delegate = self". This will work without problems

[image]
[image]